# How to create a folder in the root directory of my Java application?

Tags: java, directory, createfile

Is there a way to create a folder (with a specific name) in the main directory of my Java app.  I have a user system in my game, and whenever a new user is created, I want it to create a folder that will store all there progress in (and the folder name should be the name they put in).

For example:

From this:

[image]

To this (just by entering a username in the game):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/9950-code-create-folder-java.html):

```
File f = new File("TestDir");
try{
  if(f.mkdir())
    System.out.println("Directory Created");
  else
    System.out.println("Directory is not created");
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: The `d` in `f.mkdir()` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Define the "main directory of your Java app"? There is no such beast.

You want to be very careful when doing things like this, for security concerns. Best to define a directory in a property file and use that as a base directory for your application. Then, as already said, it is just a use of `.mkdir{,s}()` to achieve what you want.

And @C.Reed also rightly says that you should check for `mkdir()`'s return value: Java's File API is hugely flawed in that it will not throw an exception when directory/file creation/move will fail. Fortunately, Java 1.7 will cure that with its new APIs.

(an example I encountered is seeing code which would fail to `.move()` a file around: the problem is that it worked on the dev's machine, but on the production machine the directory was to be moved on another filesystem --> havoc)

Hint: use Apache's [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/)

Answer (score 1):

Establish a directory inside a sub-directory<sup>1</sup> of a known and reproducible path<sup>2</sup>.

1. E.G. a directory structure based on the package name of the main class - this helps avoid collisions with other apps.
2. A good place is `user.home` - which should be a directory that the game can read from and write to.

Answer (score -1):

If the main directory is the working direct of your application you can create a directory with

```
new File("new-dir").mkdir();
```